# Multiple long running tasks called from api [Python]

Tags: python, api, celery, gunicorn

I have to run multiple long running tasks from api. I am using python and FastAPI ,  I am not sure what is considered the best practice for it. After searching the internet , I have come up with 2 ideas , one is to run the api on gunicorn with as many workers as possible. and the second approach is to use celery and rabbitMQ, I am currently not sure how celery/rabbitmq combo helps.

There can be many tasks that can be triggered by api parallelly and the priority is to finish them as fast as possible with as little waiting as possible. The tasks usually take around 45 mins to complete.
I am not sure if i am doing something completely wrong and there is a better 'good practice' way to do that
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also work with Celery module, It has a lot of useful features.
Here you have a tutorial to set it up.
[Asynchronous Tasks with FastAPI and Celery](https://testdriven.io/blog/fastapi-and-celery/)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use FastAPI background tasks https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/